# Creating two buttons in JPanel side by side

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I am trying to make two buttons in `JPanel` side by side. I have the following code as of now:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display Shapes");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setBounds(50,100,80,30);

button.setText("Load Shapes");
panel.add(button);
JButton button2 = new JButton();
button2.setBounds(100,100,80,30);

button.setText("Sort Shapes");
panel.add(button2);

frame.add(panel);
frame.setSize(600, 600);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

When I run the code, below is the output I see. I am not sure why the second button is not appearing correctly. What could be the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: The [tag:java] & [tag:swing] tags are relevant to both questions you last asked. By sure to add relevant tags, so more people will get to see the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place where you are writing `button.setText("Sort Shapes");`, it will be `button2.setText("Sort Shapes");`

It is changing the text of the first button whose text had been set earlier